# Chakra UI icons as variables

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm using React and Chakra-UI. I'm looping through a JSON file of my links and want to generate the icons accordingly.

```
sidebar-links.json
[
  { "title": "Overview", "link": "/overview", "icon": "ViewIcon" },
  { "title": "Assets", "link": "/assets", "icon": "MinusIcon" },
  { "title": "Notifications", "link": "/notifications", "icon": "BellIcon" },
  { "title": "Settings", "link": "/settings", "icon": "SettingsIcon" },
  { "title": "Help & Support", "link": "/help", "icon": "QuestionOutlineIcon" }
]
```

```
import { BellIcon, MinusIcon,QuestionOutlineIcon,SettingsIcon,ViewIcon } from "@chakra-ui/icons";
import { Flex, Icon, Link } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { Link as ReactLink } from "react-router-dom";
import sidebarLinks from "../../data/sidebar-links.json";

const icons = {
  overview: ViewIcon,
  assets: MinusIcon,
  notifications: BellIcon,
  settings: SettingsIcon,
  help: QuestionOutlineIcon,
};

const SidebarMenu: React.FC<any> = (props) => {
  return (
          {sidebarLinks.map((link, i) => {
            const LinkIcon = icons[link.icon as keyof typeof icons]; 
            return (
              <Flex className="sidebar-items" key={i} p={2}>
                <LinkIcon />
                <Link
                  _hover={{ textDecor: "none" }}
                  as={ReactLink}
                  to={link.link}
                >
                  {link.title}
                </Link>
              </Flex>
            );
          })}
  );
};

export default SidebarMenu;
```

I get the following error
 `Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

I used the same logic and method to make the routes and don't understand why it doesn't work for Chakra UI Icons.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of make the values the name of the icons, I changed it so the icons are the components themselves.

```
import { BellIcon, MinusIcon,QuestionOutlineIcon,SettingsIcon,ViewIcon } from "@chakra-ui/icons";
import { Flex, Icon, Link } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { Link as ReactLink } from "react-router-dom";
import sidebarLinks from "../../data/sidebar-links.json";

const icons = {
  "/overview": <ViewIcon fontSize="2xl" />,
  "/assets": <MinusIcon fontSize="2xl" />,
  "/notifications": <BellIcon fontSize="2xl" />,
  "/settings": <SettingsIcon fontSize="2xl" />,
  "/help": <QuestionOutlineIcon fontSize="2xl" />,
};

const SidebarMenu: React.FC<any> = (props) => {
  return (
          {sidebarLinks.map((link, i) => {
            return (
              <Flex className="sidebar-items" key={i} p={2}>
                {icons[link.link as keyof typeof icons]}
                <Link
                  _hover={{ textDecor: "none" }}
                  as={ReactLink}
                  to={link.link}
                >
                  {link.title}
                </Link>
              </Flex>
            );
          })}
  );
};

export default SidebarMenu;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Icon component with the as prop like so

```
  <Icon as={icons[link.link]} />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import { BellIcon, MinusIcon,QuestionOutlineIcon,SettingsIcon,ViewIcon } from "@chakra-ui/icons";
    import { Stack, Icon, Link } from "@chakra-ui/react";
    import { Link as ReactLink } from "react-router-dom";
    import sidebarLinks from "../../data/sidebar-links.json";
    
    const icons = {
      overview: ViewIcon,
      assets: MinusIcon,
      notifications: BellIcon,
      settings: SettingsIcon,
      help: QuestionOutlineIcon,
    };
    
    const SidebarMenu: React.FC<any> = (props) => {
      return (
              {sidebarLinks.map((link, i) => (
                  <Stack className="sidebar-items" key={i} p={2}>
                    <LinkIcon />
  {!!icons[link.icon] && <Icon as={icons[link.icon]} />}
                    <Link
                      _hover={{ textDecor: "none
    " }}
                      as={ReactLink}
                      to={link?.link ?? ""}
                    >
                      {link?.title ?? ""}
                    </Link>
                  </Stack>
                )}
      );
    };
    
    export default SidebarMenu;
```